# DuplicateEntry app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting this error when trying to build my Project:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bolts/AggregateException.class

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
//compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//compile(name: 'calligraphy-2.1.0', ext: 'aar')
//ompile 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'
//testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2'
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.1.jar')
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.13.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, just added this:

```
compile ('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0'){
    exclude module: 'bolts-android'
}
```